# Packing integer as floats, finding original ints

Tags: image, floating-point, int, type-conversion

We are packing two 12 bits integers into three 8 bits RGB colors to convey  values to a GPU.

The process goes like this:

1. Two 16 bits integers are generated (`U` and `V`)
2. They are decimated to two 12 bits integers (we are dropping the less significant bits)
3. Those 24 bits of data are packed in three 8 bits integers as RGB colors. The packing goes like this (`Rx` means `Bit x of channel R`)

`R8  R7  R6  R5  R4  R3  R2 R1 | G8 G7 G6 G5
U16 U15 U14 U13 U12 U11 U10 U9   U8 U7 U6 U5
 G4  G3  G2  G1 |  B8  B7  B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1
V16 V15 V14 V13   V12 V11 V10 V8 V7 V6 V5 V4`

4. I don't receive the RGB colors as integers but as three 32bits floating points values, ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 for each color channel, and all image operations in that software are made in floats.

This is the original two 16 bits image (converted to jpeg for displaying in the browser, this file is not the actual data source). `U` is encoded to the red channel, `V` to the green.

[image]

And this is the packed version where the green channel holds the less significant bits of `U` and the most significant bits of `V`:

[image]

How can I get back to the original image (16 bits integers -> 32 bits floats) using only floating point operations ?

Many thanks !

Comment: What is the mapping from the packed integers to the floats?

Comment: Int are unsigned, 0 int -> 0.0 float, MAX_INT -> 1.0 float

Comment: Which bits of the packed integer go to which float?

Comment: Can you force images of your choice into the process? If so, I would start with flat simple primary color images, such as pure red.